# Marry RouteData.Values with Action Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm setting some `RouteData` inside a custom `Action Filter`

```
filterContext.RouteData.Values.Add("accountId", accountId);
filterContext.RouteData.Values.Add("permission", (int)permission);
```

Then I have an action like the following

```
public ActionResult Get(Guid accountId, int permission, int id) {

}
```

**Can I marry the `RouteData` values to the action parameters via a route? If so, how?**

I'd like to just use an URL such as

```
http://localhost/Users/Get/1
```

*They route data is present and can be retrieved by using*

```
Guid accountId = (Guid)RouteData.Values["accountId"];
Permission permission = (Permission)RouteData.Values["permission"];
```

Comment: I want to populate the action parameters using RouteData that I set in a custom Action Filter so that it's not really appended to the URL. Basically I'm retreiving some values from cache/session that are set on login and need to use those values as the base for a number of controller actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom `ValueProvider`, not an action filter.
For more information, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try, this question is directly related to the first answer on my previous question. Do you think a custom ValueProvider is the way to go considering my scenario?

Comment: Also, not ALL actions will require these 'hidden' route data values. What happens to the ones that don't use them?

Comment: @Marko: The model binder will ask your ValueProvider whether it has values for any of the parameter names.  If it doesn't ask you for those two names, your ValueProvider shouldn't do anything.

Comment: Hmm ok, the only issue is that the NameValueCollection only accepts strings while I have an integer and guid action parameters. Did you manage to have a look at the other question and see whether this is a good idea to start with?

Comment: @Marko: You can make a custom `IValueProvider` that returns whatever you want.  The idea seems OK.

Comment: @SLaks i am using action filter in webapi and authenticating/authorizing on the basis of posted values/action/controller name.So how can i get parameters in my action filter so that i can auth/unauthorize a person

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ActionParameters property:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ActionParameters["accountId"] = Guid.NewGuid();
        filterContext.ActionParameters["permission"] = 456;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [MyActionFilter]
    public ActionResult Index(Guid accountId, int permission, int id)
    {
        return Content(string.Format("accountId={0}, permission={1}", accountId, permission));
    }
}
```

and when you request `/home/index/123` the following is shown:

```
accountId=f72fddb8-1c35-467b-a479-b2668fd5b2ec, permission=456
```